# How to create text-filter for dropdown menu elements in IOS

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, user-interface

In android, if I want a user to select something from a large list (100+ items) I would normally do something like this where the user types like an autocomplete.

[image] [image]

I want to do something similar on iOS but I can't find anything like the dropdown menu I had on android. I realize I could do the search bar at the top and a table view below it but I have more text fields below it.

There are pickers but they're not exactly a good choice when there are so many items in the list

I've been trying to find a way to use something like this https://harvesthq.github.io/chosen/ but I'm new to Xcode and iOS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have tried your problem and got the solution. try using UISearchBar and Table views
initially the table view will be hidden and as the user types the delegate method from Search Bar will be called and table view will appear.

The user interface should contain:

1. A search bar (> iOS 8)
2. A table view

Connect the datasource and delegate methods appropriately

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISearchBar *searchbar;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *orgData;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *data;

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    self.orgData = @[@"New York, NY", @"Los Angeles, CA", @"Chicago, IL", @"Houston, TX",
              @"Philadelphia, PA", @"Phoenix, AZ", @"San Diego, CA", @"San Antonio, TX",
              @"Dallas, TX", @"Detroit, MI", @"San Jose, CA", @"Indianapolis, IN",
              @"Jacksonville, FL", @"San Francisco, CA", @"Columbus, OH", @"Austin, TX",
              @"Memphis, TN", @"Baltimore, MD", @"Charlotte, ND", @"Fort Worth, TX"];

    self.data = self.orgData;
    [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
}

-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    return 1;
}

-(NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    return self.data.count;
}

-(UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"cell"];

    cell.textLabel.text = self.data[indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    self.searchbar.text = self.data[indexPath.row];
    [self.tableView setHidden:YES];
}

-(BOOL)searchBarShouldBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar
{
    [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
    return YES;
}

-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{
    [self.tableView setHidden:NO];
    self.data = ([searchText isEqualToString:@""])? self.orgData : [self filterArrayUsingSearchText:searchText];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

-(NSArray *) filterArrayUsingSearchText:(NSString*) searchText
{
    NSPredicate *resultPredicate = [NSPredicate
                                    predicateWithFormat:@"SELF contains[cd] %@",
                                    searchText];

    return [self.orgData filteredArrayUsingPredicate:resultPredicate];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think pickers can be used but not as is.

Have you tried a textField but changing the inputView of it for your picker?

It will open the picker instead of the keyboard. So far this is the best approach I came up with (because there is no native equivalent of dropdowns, you can make it yoursel though...)